# How do I determine the intersection of between two parametric planes?

Tags: parametric, plane-geometry, intersection-theory

```
x = t + 5
y = 2t - 6
z = 3t - 1


x = 4u + 11
y = -2u - 4
z = 16u + 11
```

I have tried making each value equal to one another, such as

x1 = x2,
y1 = y2

Or making them a system and get the individual values to then replace their respective values (x,y,z), but even then I'm unable to reach a conclusion as if they're intersecting or not.

Comment: Those are two parametric *lines*, not two parametric planes. You are correct that you are looking for $t$ and $u$ such that $t+5 = 4u+11$, $2t-6 = -2u-4$, and $3t-1 = 16u+11$.

Comment: As stated, parametric lines.  I would say: take those 6 equations, then eliminate $x,y,z$.  Result is (in a general case) 3 equations in 2 unknowns $t,u$.  That system may have no solutions (the two lines do not intersect), one solution (the two lines intersect in a point), or infinitely many solutions (the two lines coincide).

Comment: Thank you. Will look into it!